# Download image flair regularly and include from local server

Tags: support, flair, legal

I would like to include the SE image flair on my website. However, for various reasons (mostly privacy, some legal uncertainties), I would prefer if this image was included locally, rather than causing a request to the SE servers each time someone visits my website.

That is, I would get a cron job to download `http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1912106.png` every few days, put it in a some directory on my server and then use

```
<a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/1912106">
<img src="http://example.com/flair.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Claudius on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for Claudius on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites">
</a>
```

to include the image.

Is this allowed/accepted from the point of the SE trademark guidances (never mind whether it would qualify as fair use or some such thing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would not violate any trademarks. The only thing on that image which actually belongs to them is the site logo (or logos if it's the combined flair). So as long as you're linked back to your profile like a normal flair image, there's absolutely nothing wrong with downloading and hosting it yourself. Everything else on there is just text, some colored circles, and *your* Gravatar; it's not like they can "own" that information.

Answer (score 4):

You are encouraged to use the flair image wherever you want to show it; it won't matter where it is loaded *from* when you include it in your site.

You'll even save the Stack Exchange team a (tiny) amount of bandwidth by hosting the image yourself.